# Relating Objects in CakePHP

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, relational-database

I have Users and I have Courses. I am trying to create a "Join" button for the users when they're viewing the course list in order to subscribe them to the Courses.

I was told to use

```
class Course extends AppModel
{
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
}
```

and

```
class User extends AppModel
{
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Course');
}
```

But I don't know how to implement the actual button and the posting of the info to a table called `courses_users`

Where do I implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sent the student ID and the course ID to your `saveAll()` method. You could do this through your courses controller as follows:

```
<?php
class CoursesController extends AppController {

    public function join($courseId) {
        $data = array(
            'Course' => array(
                'id' => $courseId
            ),
            'Student' => array(
                'id' => $this->Auth->user('id') // ID of logged in user
            )
        );

        if ($this->Course->saveAll($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash( __('Successfully joined course.'));
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash( __('Error joining course.'));
        }

        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

This is just a simple example. You’ll need to tweak it to your app, and add any validation etc.

Comment: CakePHP is based on the principle of Convention over Configuration, when you have a HABTM relationship between the Course model and the User model, it assumes there is a courses_users table in your DB and will write to it automagically when you save Users associated to a Course, even if the function called is $this->Course->saveAll() (which saves associated data).

Comment: @Chris this is perfect actually - it's working great except that when another user registers for the same course, it writes over the file with the new username even though there's a $hasAndBelongsToMany attached to both objects. Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: The default behavior of saving HABTM data for CakePHP is to delete all records associated to the one you save, then creating the ones from your data (as explained in the link below for the unique option) : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm , a solution is to declare your habtm relation with 'unique' => keepExisting.

Comment: @Chris So I tried 'unique' => 'keepExisting' on both and it kept writing over. false was close except it allowed for duplicates (so user 5 course 8 was acceptable.) I guess I need to figure out how to check to make sure the exact match of user/course already exists?

Answer (score 3):

If you are this new I would suggest using the cake bake utility which will examine your tables , ask some questions about the relations and build the model, controller and views for all the basic create, update and delete operations in your database.  You can then modify them for your needs.  That's how I still do it to save lots of time.

Comment: AbraCadaver is right, you will benefit from automatically baked Models/Controllers/Views to simplify your basic tasks and learn how simple things are done. If you want an UI rather than a console to bake your files, use this tool : http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/cakes

Comment: Thanks for the tip, everyone. I will definitely check it out.